# I am trying to display the home screen of this chat app and adding the time sent of messages

Tags: android, ios, flutter

> this is the message.dart and I'm having an error of "String is not a subtype of bool"

'''

```
return StreamBuilder(

  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("chats")
      .orderBy("time", descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var chatDoc = snapshot.data!.docs;

      return ListView.builder(
        reverse: false,
        itemCount: chatDoc.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => messageBubble(
          chatDoc[index]['displayName'],
          chatDoc[index]['email'],
          chatDoc[index]['text'],
          chatDoc[index]['uid'] == currentUser,
          key: ValueKey<String>(chatDoc[index].id),
          time: chatDoc[index]['time'].toDate(),

        ),
      );
```

'''

> and this is the messageBubble.dart function

'''

```
class messageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final bool isMe;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final DateTime time;
  final Key key;

  const messageBubble(this.message, this.isMe, this.name, this.email,
      {required this.key, required this.time});
```

'''

Comment: Would you show us the implementation of `messageBubble` please?

Comment: sorry sir i am new to stackoverflow, how can I add the code of my messageBubble.dart here?

Comment: To edit a question, first press the edit button, next, in order to write code, you need to put three backtick characters ( ` ), then on a new line, copy-paste you code, and then on another new line another three backtick characters. PS currently your question is 100% code, which is not allowed in stack overflow, I recommend you also add an in-depth explanation of your code and your problem before showing the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done sir. please tell me if you need more of the codes. thank you guys

Comment: sir @h8moss I updated the question I included the messageBubble implementation. thank you sir

Comment: @GrayAnthrax I see now, I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I reccomend whenever you make a constructor, you always use named parameters to avoid this sort of confusion.

Your `messageBubble` constructor takes the following parameters in the following order: `message`, `isMe`, `name`, `email`, and you are passing information in this order: `chatDoc[index]['displayName'], chatDoc[index]['email'], chatDoc[index]['text'], chatDoc[index]['uid'] == currentUser,`

This means that `message` will be `chatDoc[index]['displayName']`, `isMe` will be `chatDoc[index]['email']` (which will be an error because I presume `email` is some string, but `isMe` is a boolean value) and so on and so forth.

To fix this, as I said, I recommend all parameters become named:

from

```
const messageBubble(this.message, this.isMe, this.name, this.email,
      {required this.key, required this.time});
```

to

```
const messageBubble({
  required this.message,
  required this.isMe, 
  required this.name,
  required this.email,
  required this.key, 
  required this.time});
```

this means that when construction `messageBubble` you will:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) => messageBubble(
  name: chatDoc[index]['displayName'],
  email: chatDoc[index]['email'],
  text: chatDoc[index]['text'],
  isMe: chatDoc[index]['uid'] == currentUser,
  key: ValueKey<String>(chatDoc[index].id),
  time: chatDoc[index]['time'].toDate(),
),
```

Of course, if you don't want to do that, simply fixing the order of the parameters should fix the issue:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) => messageBubble(
  chatDoc[index]['text'],
  chatDoc[index]['uid'] == currentUser,
  chatDoc[index]['displayName'],
  chatDoc[index]['email'],
  key: ValueKey<String>(chatDoc[index].id),
  time: chatDoc[index]['time'].toDate(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd include the full stack trace here. Looks like something in your `chatDoc` is a String and you're trying to pass it into something of type bool.